# Is the answer to this improper integral ∞ or -∞?

Tags: calculus

The following integral is discontinuous at x = 0, $$\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{x}\:dx$$

Of course the proper answer to this integral is that it **diverges**, but I'm just curious whether the prior answer before concluding that this integral diverges is $\infty$ or $-\infty$?

---

**1) When just computing the integral with standard integration rules, it becomes the following:**

$${ln|x|_0^1}\: = ln(1) - ln(0) = 0 -∞ = -∞ $$

**2) When applying improper integral techniques, it becomes the following:**

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} (ln|x|_t^1) = lim_{t \to 0^+}-ln|t|=-(-∞) = ∞$$

Noting that both **diverge** regardless of being $-\infty$ or $\infty$, I just want to know which prior answer before the divergence  conclusion is correct, $-\infty$ or $\infty$?  Note sure if my math is wrong but I think there is some ambiguity here.

Comment: $\ln(0) = \infty$ ???

Comment: Not sure if ln(0) is undefined, but I just saw a solution somewhere that computing this integral as shown in my first method is -∞

Comment: If ln(0) is undefined, how would the prior step/answer be written? Would it just be ∞ or just write diverges

Comment: Your second method (taking the limit) is the correct approach.

Comment: Also another question , is applying the improper integral techniques necessary for this integral? Just applying the regular integration rules give the same answer but faster. As this calculator shows, it uses the first method https://www.symbolab.com/solver/definite-integral-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7Ddx

Comment: There is no “regular integration technique” here. Both $1/x$ and $\ln(x)$ are *undefined* at $x=0$.

Comment: @Jtheconstant Does the below answer clarify the query?

Comment: Recall the intuition, that for positive functions the integral is the area beneath the curve. But there is simply no way that this area can be negative and definitely not $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you think 
$$\int_0^1 \, \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln|x| \,\bigg|_0^1 = \ln(1) - \ln(0)$$
is a valid move, but it's not. You can't simply plug-in $0$ into the $\ln(x)$ because $\ln$ is undefined at $x = 0$. In fact, the domain of $\ln$ is $(0,\infty)$. Even if we generalize $\ln(x)$ to $\ln|x|$ the enlarged domain of $\ln|x|$ is $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$.

Therefore, you *must* take the right-hand limit.

For a clearer example, consider the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x-1} dx.$$
If we evaluate this integral without limits, we get
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x-1} dx = \ln|x-1|\,\bigg|_0^1 = -1 - \frac{1}{0},$$
which is clearly ridiculous. Again, this is because the number $1$ does not belong to the domain of the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1}$, similar to how $0$ does not belong to the domain of the natural logarithm.

Therefore, the correct way to evaluate this integral is to take a left-hand limit:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x-1} dx = \lim_{t\to 1^-}\int_0^t \frac{1}{x-1} dx = \lim_{t \to 1^-} \, \ln|x-1|\,\bigg|_0^t = -\lim_{t \to 1^-} \ln|x-1| = -(-\infty) = \infty$$

**Edit**
If you ever see notation like $\ln(0)$, or I've even seen $\ln(\infty)$, understand that this is shorthand for some limit.

Comment: Yes this is what I was asking: whether the first method would be appropriate since we can only say that ln(0) is -∞ when taking of the limit of ln|x| as it approaches 0 from right hand side. So, the first method is wrong when concluding that it is -∞?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Jtheconstant I see what you're saying. So just to add something,  not only is not taking limits mathematically incorrect, one will also get wrong answers, as in the example you provided. But, again, you're right =)